# highlight of elasticsearch in java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

i need to highlight the match word in a document,
in java client.
i don't know where to fix highlight object
this is my java code for search:

```
            HighlightBuilder highlightBuilder = new HighlightBuilder().postTags("<highlight>").preTags("</highlight>").field("filename");
            SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("userdoc"); 
            SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder(); 
            BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("filedata",word));
            if(usertype.equals("user"))
            {
                queryBuilder.filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("email", email));
            }
            searchSourceBuilder.query(queryBuilder);
            searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
            searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `highlightBuilder` to `searchSourceBuilder` as shown below:

```java
searchSourceBuilder.query(queryBuilder);
searchSourceBuilder.highlighter(highlightBuilder);
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```

Using below code you can get highlighting as well:

```java
SearchHits hits = searchResponse.getHits();
for (SearchHit hit : hits.getHits()) {
    Map<String, HighlightField> highlightFields = hit.getHighlightFields();
    HighlightField highlight = highlightFields.get("title"); 
    Text[] fragments = highlight.fragments();  
    String fragmentString = fragments[0].string();
}
```

Please check [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-search.html#java-rest-high-search-response-highlighting) documentation for more information about search API.

Comment: how can i get highlighted responce

Comment: Please try it out and check if it working for you or not.

Comment: Updated my answer for highlgihting response.

Comment: yes it work.., could you tell me how to get highlighted response?

Comment: Updated my answer for highlighted response as well. please check.

Comment: how to print all highlighted word in my document? my highlighter is send one highlighted word only, but my document contains 3 word... so what should i do?

Comment: could you please rais seperate question or check elasticsearch highlighting documentation ? you need to increase fragments size for getting more words but if your all words are split across text then it difficult to get all words highlighted.